# Should The Plug of UPS Always Plugged?

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

Which is better for lifespan:

- Switch off the UPS and plug off **or**
- Switch off the UPS and leave it plugged in.

Consider this two statements and give seperate replies:

1. Which is better for >1 Month (the ups will be off)
2. Which is better for 1 day (the ups will be off)

Comment: If the UPS has a lead-acid battery, do nothing special and just turn it off. If you do not wish to leave it plugged in for long-term storage (>1 month), store it in a cold location (between 0C and 10C). [Source](http://www.mpoweruk.com/storage.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It has a lead-acid battery, so for waiting 1 day should i do nothing or plug off?
The temp. of room is around 25C~

Comment: If just for a few days, you should just turn it off if it's not being used (but unplugging it won't hurt it). Unplugging it for a long period of time (>1 month) will hurt it and cause sulfation and reduce the battery capacity, unless it is stored between 10C and 0C.